# Does Vim has a command-search option?

Tags: vim, command-line-interface, vim-plugin

Can I find commands by typing, i.e.: `:sc undo`, then it would display `Press u`, or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. The main `:help` page includes (under *Get specific help*) a table of the syntax used for looking up commands in the various modes. Most plugins also install their own help pages, so extensions are covered by this, too.

To list commands starting with a certain prefix, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to get a list of all matching commands, or step through candidates with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Something similar can be done for mappings, e.g. `:nmap <Leader>` lists all mappings triggered by the <kbd>\</kbd> key (by default). With `:verbose` in front of it, you'll also get information about which script defined those.

Comment: Don't forget `:helpgrep` either.